# Escaping xsrf in Tornado with javascript POST

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, post, tornado

I have a simple form I would like to submit to a Tornado POST and I am running xsrf in tornado.  The following produces the known error: *'_xsrf' argument missing from POST*

Has anyone solved how to submit the xsrf (like *{% module xsrf_form_html() %}*) in a regular HTML form using javascript?  Here is the code:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
    {% raw xsrf_form_html() %}  # DOES NOT WORK!
   <p><input type="text" id="field1" value=""></p>
</form>

<button id="button">UPDATE</button>

<script>
  button.onclick = function changeField() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/chatdata", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            value: document.getElementById("field1").value
        }))
    };
</script>
```

Comment: if `_xsrf` is supposed to be a posted field (ie x-www-form-urlencoded) you are not sending it correctly, it would be something like `xhr.send("_xsrf=yourtoken")` replace yourtoken with the value you would get from the generated input field from xsrf_form_html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That makes sense up to the point where the token value is captured to send, ("_xsrf=yourtoken").  This is where I am stuck as the templating performs this function automagically with the decorator.  Any ideas on how to obtain that would be golden.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

`xsrf_form_html` is for traditional html forms using `x-www-form-urlencoded`. It won't be recognized if you submit your form as JSON. To use non-form-based encodings with Tornado's XSRF protection, pass the XSRF token as a <s>`X-XSRF-Token`</s> `X-XSRFToken` HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation page](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html) you would just create a request that has a `_xsrf` request field, for example a `x-www-urlencoded` string of `_xsrf=yourtoken`. The way you had it you were sending just some JSON that had a `value` property, ie `{"value":"token"}`.

Now you can get the token in a couple ways from what I have seen, either through a set cookie or from the field that is generated from the `xsrf_form_html()` call.

From cookie

```
//helper function to read cookie, from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html sample
function getCookie(name) {
    var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
    return r ? r[1] : undefined;
}

var data = "_xsrf="+getCookie('_xsrf');
//note using this method you don't set the content-type, 
//you want it to default to x-www-urlencoded
xhr.send(data);
```

Note you would have to build up the string to contain your other input form fields, either directly or through library methods like [jQuery's serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize)

If want to just use the data straight from the form without the hassle of grabbing each input and generating a proper x-www-urlencoded string yourself; Then continue using `xsrf_form_html()` and create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object from that form and send that. When you pass a form element to `FormData()` it will collect all the input values for you.

```
var data = new FormData( document.getElementById('form_field') );
//again no need to set the content-type as it will be automatically set internally
xhr.send(data);
//You could also use library methods like jQuery's serialize()
var data = jQuery('#form_field').serialize();
xhr.send(data);
```

Using FormData helps if you don't know how to get a reference to the generated field directly. Though it would more than likely have `name="_xsrf"` so a selector like `input[name="_xsrf"]` should find it. Though you would have to look at the generated html to find out.

```
var data = "_xsrf="+document.querySelector('input[name="_xsrf"]').value
```